# How to make a repsonsive design so H2 get its maximum font size in a 1-line DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, responsive-design

How do I make a headline, `H2`, to fit into the current width of a `DIV`.

I want the `H2` to get the maximum font size, displaying its full context (without using overflow to cut or hide its content), while not breaking into a second line within the `DIV`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways - some more complex than others. There's a few JavaScript plugins that can handle this which might serve you best.

A simple but effective CSS-only way would be to use the viewport width (`vw`) as the value for font-size. Here's an example using `white-space: nowrap` in conjunction: https://jsfiddle.net/6tueLheq/

HTML:

```
<h2>
  Hello there i don't break to the next line no matter what the width!
</h2>
```

CSS:

```
h2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 3vw;
}
```

NOTE - this way is not perfect by any means - I'd suggest using something like FitText: http://fittextjs.com/, which is quite powerful.

More info on viewport units: https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Comment: The `vw` method doesn't work for my case. It's based on viewport size, but I need to have it based on `DIV ` width, because it's a responsive design, my `DIV` can be large or small in different situation. Will FitText handle the situation where `H2` is wrapped inside a responsive `DIV`?

Comment: @KDX hmm, the size of the h2 itself is possible of course, but the text within it is tricky without JS. Fittext can handle most scenarios, I've not had a situation that it doesn't work but you might need to experiment as every situation can be different. From what you describe, I think it'll work just fine...

Answer (score 1):

**Js Way :**

You can use Javascript based plugins like FitTextJs http://fittextjs.com/. This plugin allows you to have headings that can resize based on the current device width.

**CSS Way:**

You can provide the font size using **vw** units.  This will scale the font size based on current viewport size.

E.g., 1vw will direct the browser to use the font size as 1% of current viewport width.

But please check if your targeted browsers support this unit before Implementation.

**Custom implementation :**

I have used following way to design fluid websites,  that should align and appear identical in all possible screen resolutions.

If the font size at 320 px is 12px, then the mobile font multiplication factor will be

320px has font size as 12px

Then what should be the font size at 480px

The calculation will be

```
X = ( 12 * 480)  / 320;
```

Once the font size is dynamically calculated,  you can set the font size to body tag and set font sizes for dependent elements in %.

e.g.,

```
h2 { font-size:110%;}
```

This method  is fun to implement.

But there will be a slight delay before the new calculated font size to be applied on window resize or orientation changes